# If $f$ is Lipchitz in $[0,1] $with constant $L$ show that $|f(x)-B_n(f)|<\frac{L}{2 \sqrt{n}}$ where $B_n(f)$ is the Bernstein polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous Lipchitz in $[0,1] $with constant $L$ show that for $n\geq 1$ we have that $\forall x\in [0,1]$the inequality  $|f(x)-B_n(f)|<\frac{L}{2 \sqrt{n}}$  holds where $B_n(f)$  is the Bernstein polynomial.

*Attempt*

Let us consider $p_{n,k}(x)=C_{n}^{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ and $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n})p_{n,k}(x)$.

Now notice that $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf(x)p_{n,k}(x)$ and $p_n(x)=B_n(f)$ therefore our approach is
$$|f(x)-p_n(x)|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(f(x)-f\left( \frac{k}{n}\right)\right)p_{n,k} \right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n \left| f(x)-f \left( \frac{k}{n}\right)\right|$$ and for the condition of Lipchitz we have the following
$$ |f(x)-p_n(x)| \leq L\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left| x-\frac{k}{n}\right|$$ I wish that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left| x-\frac{k}{n}\right|< \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
but I can´t bound this expression, any help, comment or hint was useful

Comment: The last summation is $\frac{n+1}{2}$ for $x=0$, so you need to estimate somewhere before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer contained an error.

Comment: How is possible justify the existence of it $k_0$? for instance I don´t watch immediately how find such $k_0$

Comment: Divide the interval $[0,1]$ in intervals $\left [ \frac{k}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right )$ of length $\frac{1}{n}$. Since they are pairwise disjoint and $x \in [0, 1]$, we have that $x$ belongs in one, and only one, of them. Except if $x=1$ but then $f(1)=p_n(1)$.